# Iterate through list using LinQ to get desired result

Tags: c#, linq, list

```
 public class ItemDetails
    {
        public List<string> XAxis { get; set; }

        public List<string> YAxis { get; set; }

        public List<string> Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Activity
    {
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }

        public string ActivityValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityQuarterModel
    {
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }

        public Quarter Quarter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Quarter : IEquatable<Quarter>
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int QuarterIndex { get; set; }


        public Quarter FromDate(DateTime date)
        {
            Quarter quarter = new Quarter()
            {
                Year = date.Year,
                QuarterIndex = 1 + (date.Month - 1) / 3
            };
            return quarter;
        }

        public string GetQuarter(DateTime date)
        {
            string quarter = "Q" + (1 + (date.Month - 1) / 3) + " " + date.Year;
            return quarter;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object otherItem)
        {
            Quarter other = otherItem as Quarter;
            if (other == null) return false;
            return this.Equals(other);
        }

        public bool Equals(Quarter otherItem)
        {
            if (otherItem == null) return false;
            return Year == otherItem.Year && QuarterIndex == otherItem.QuarterIndex;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 23;
                hash = (hash * 31) + Year;
                hash = (hash * 31) + QuarterIndex;
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Quarter>
    {
        public bool Equals(Quarter lhs, Quarter rhs)
        {
            if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return false;
            return lhs.Year == rhs.Year && lhs.QuarterIndex == rhs.QuarterIndex;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Quarter item)
        {
            if (item == null) return 0;
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 23;
                hash = (hash * 31) + item.Year;
                hash = (hash * 31) + item.QuarterIndex;
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ItemDetails itemDetails = new ItemDetails()
            {
                XAxis = new List<string>() { "Q1 2013", "Q2 2013"},
                YAxis = new List<string>() { "Activity1", "Activity2"},
                Value = new List<string>() { "ActivityType3", "ActivityType5" }
            };

            List<ActivityQuarterModel> sourceList = new List<ActivityQuarterModel>()
            {
                new ActivityQuarterModel() { Activity = new Activity(){ ActivityName = "Activity1", ActivityValue = "ActivityType3"}, Quarter = new Quarter() { QuarterIndex = 2, Year = 2013}},
                new ActivityQuarterModel() { Activity = new Activity(){ ActivityName = "Activity1", ActivityValue = "ActivityType5"}, Quarter = new Quarter() { QuarterIndex = 1, Year = 2013}},
                new ActivityQuarterModel() { Activity = new Activity(){ ActivityName = "Activity1", ActivityValue = "ActivityType3"}, Quarter = new Quarter() { QuarterIndex = 3, Year = 2013}},
                new ActivityQuarterModel() { Activity = new Activity(){ ActivityName = "Activity2", ActivityValue = "ActivityType3"}, Quarter = new Quarter() { QuarterIndex = 1, Year = 2013}},
                new ActivityQuarterModel() { Activity = new Activity(){ ActivityName = "Activity1", ActivityValue = "ActivityType5"}, Quarter = new Quarter() { QuarterIndex = 1, Year = 2013}},
            };

        }
    }
```

I have data in ItemDetails which I am using for filtering.
Need to filter   List sourceList

How to retrieve list of ActivityValues having quarter "Q1 2013" and activity name "Activity1"?
ActivityValues should be provided ActivityValues. Here they are "ActivityType3", "ActivityType5"

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I am unable to get the logic of linq here.

Answer (score 1):

Your itemDetails list is seemingly unrelated to the values, and based on you example the results are "ActivityType5" and "ActivityType5"

```
var activityValues = (from aqm in sourceList
                      where (aqm.Activity.ActivityName == "Activity1" &&
                             (aqm.Quarter.QuarterIndex == 1 && aqm.Quarter.Year == 2013)) // Made the assumption that "Q1 2013" is QuarterIndex = 1 and Year = 2013
                      select aqm.Activity.ActivityValue).ToList();
```

Comment: How to retrieve activity values which are present in target activity values list?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean as the above query will return you the string values stored in Activity.ActivityValue. i.e. "ActivityType5"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood this right but is this what you are looking for?

```
var results = sourceList.Where(a => a.Quarter.QuarterIndex.Equals(1) 
    && a.Quarter.Year.Equals(2013) 
    && a.Activity.ActivityName.Equals("Activity1") 
    && (a.Activity.ActivityValue.Equals("ActivityType3") || a.Activity.ActivityValue.Equals("ActivityType5")));
```